# Square in a quadrant

Tags: geometry, circles

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECHpJueKN7c

Timestamp:- 1:28

Original Question

[image]

**My doubt:-** Why does the perpendicular bisector to the side of square constructed has to pass through the center of quadrant ? or why does the line through center will be the perpendicular bisector to the side of the square ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perpendicular bisector of any chord of a circle passes through the center of that circle.